# My cat's chin is black

Tags: cats, behavior, health

My cat’s chin is black. He cries all the time, so I think he also feels pain due to this condition. Also he can’t close his mouth.

I don't know what to do, should we visit a vet? He’s been like that for the last 3 days and I tried to clean the stains, but he gets aggressive (it might be because of the mentioned pain).

Comment: Can you clarify what in particular is black? The fur or the flesh underneath the fur? Is this condition new? How long has it been like this? This information would help the community understand what's going on more specifically. Also, if possible, quality photos would help immensely.

Comment: Yes, you should **go to a vet as soon as possible** instead of waiting for answers from strangers on the internet. Your cat is clearly in pain. If he cannot close his mouth, he surely has problems eating food and drinking water. If this went on for 3 days, he might be in severe danger of kidney damage due to dehydration. **Do not wait any longer and go to a vet as soon as possible**.

Comment: I will take him. I just asked first

Comment: Bcs i wrote this at 3AM

Comment: @Harry It's ok to feel insecure and ask for help, but on this site we sometimes are afraid that pet owners hesitate to go to a vet for too long because they wait for a magical answer that makes the vet (and the corresponding costs) unnecessary. I hope your furry friend is well.